# How can I calculate win percentage needed based on risk/reward ratio?

Tags: probability, risk-assessment

Let's say I have calculated the probability of a win in two games to be $60\%$.
I have $2$ bets I am looking at.

For the first bet I need to risk $165$  to win $85$.

For the second bet I need to risk $263$  to win $237$.

Risk/Reward for first bet is $1.94$ and for second $1.1$.

If I calculate first bet to be $(0.6 * 85) - (0.4 * 165) = -15$ it is losing.

If I calculate second bet to be $(0.6 * 237) - (0.4 * 263) = 37$ it is winning.

But how do I get the minimum win percentage I need for a bet based of money I am risking?

I get confused because the risk is more than reward. All calculations I have seen assume risk is less than reward.

Comment: So you want a non-negative expected value?

Comment: Yes, I get confused because the risk is more than reward. All calculations I have seen assume risk is less than reward.

Comment: How much money do you bet in the first game, 165?

Comment: Yes, I bet 165 to win 85 in first game and 263 to win 237 in second game.

Comment: Then the inequality is $E(X)=p\cdot 237- (1-p)\cdot 263+p\cdot 85- (1-p)\cdot 165\geq 0$

Comment: If the risk is always greater than the winning then p must be greater than $0.5$ to obtain a non-negative expected value.

Comment: Thanks, I think I formulated this question wrong though. The expected value calculation is 100% correct but I still need to understand win percentage needed for a bet given risk and reward.

Comment: If you want a non-negative expected value see the inequality in the comments.

Comment: Got it , thanks a lot!

Comment: You´re welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like in your case you would win the amount over the bet. So you would do something like this $win\implies 165+85$ and $lose\implies -165$ so you’re expected value should be something like this assuming that $p=P(win)$ $$\mathbb{E} (bet)= p(165+85)-(1-p)(-165)>0 $$
Solving this for p will give you the interval such that you can have an expected positive value of money after betting. Please note that however this is only the probability, people might have different preferences associated to how much they’d like to risk.

Comment: thanks simonegiancola, need to do some calculations to make sure I understand.

Comment: It is not right, that you have +165 if you win and -165 if you loose. If you bet 165 then it is negative in both cases.